# hg: replacing directory contents in one change

Tags: mercurial

With hg, how can I replace the contents of a directory in one change?

More specifically, I have headers for a large C++ library checked into my repo and I'd like to update them (including adding and removing files) to the latest version of the library. And I'd like to do this in one change, rather than first a removal of the old version and then addition of the new, which would break tests and produce unhelpful diffs.

Answer (score 4):

## Within your mercurial repo:

```
# Change to parent directory of your vendor directory
cd vendor_dir/..
rm -rf vendor_dir
# unpack/copy/checkout new vendor sources into a new vendor_dir
# Tell mercurial to figure out what changed
# Feel free to play with the similarity percentage and the (-n) do nothing switch
hg addremove --similarity 70 vendor_dir
hg commit vendor_dir
```

Updated:

1. Changed to work on the parent directory since `hg rm *` within `vendor_dir` misses dot files, if any.
2. Change from `hg rm` to `rm -rf` because I wrongly assumed that addremove after rm would do the right thing. Hint: it doesn't.
3. Realized that the default similarity of 100% is not appropriate for vendor releases.

Comment: You sure the hg rm is needed? It seems to result in only added files in the commit. When I omit it I get added, changed, and removed files.

Comment: I agree. I don't think the `hg rm` command is needed. Just the `--addremove` parameter on the `hg commit` command.

Comment: You guys were correct. I went back and tested and addremove doesn't work as I thought it would after hg rm.

Comment: Pure addremove without `--similarity` will break history of vendor files, BTW

Comment: @LazyBadger: By default addremove detects 100% identical name changes, but you're right that we should drop the level. What level do you think?

Comment: It depends... For not-a-big-files I usually starting around 70-80, but test results with `-n` (in separate addremove command)

Comment: Thanks @LazyBadger, I've updated the answer. It's a shame that there's no similarity option for commit to reduce the commands. Well, there's always aliases.

Answer (score 2):

If they are all changed then, (assuming a flat directory structure:

```
hg remove \path\to\directory\to\replace\*.h
copy \path\to\new\files\*.* \path\to\directory\to\replace\
hg add \path\to\directory\to\replace\*.*
hg commit -m "Library SoAndSo headers replaced"
hg push
```

The first line says forget all the files on the next commit but then the new ones are added in the same commit - *remember only the last but one line actually changes the local copy of the repository and it only becomes public on the last line*.

If you do have sub-directories then you can just remove the `*.h` on the first line, use `xcopy` or explorer to copy the new directory structure into place and remove the `*.*` on the 3rd line.

Comment: Do you mean: hg add \path\to\directory\to\replace\ ?

Comment: @Taylor Oops! Yes - will fix.

Comment: Ok, and there are subdirectories of the header file dir. How does that change things?